# DefaultKeyBinding.dict method not working to move cursor from word to word(which is by default options + left/right)

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, karabiner

I created a DefaultKeyBinding.dict in `~/Library/KeyBindings` and copied this code to change how I can move from words to words to **command+left/right** instead of **options + left/right**. But it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
  "@\UF702" = moveWordLeft:;
  "@\UF703" = moveWordRight:;
  "@$\UF702" = moveWordLeftAndModifySelection:;
  "@$\UF703" = moveWordRightAndModifySelection:;
}
```

Also, I installed Karabiner but did not understand how to do it in there. Can anyone guide please. I miss the ease of doing it in windows. Using Mac Big Sur 11.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Karabiner and used a rule set [https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=finder%20search#:~:text=Windows%20shortcuts%20on-,macOS,-Import](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=finder%20search#:%7E:text=Windows%20shortcuts%20on-,macOS,-Import) to make it more like Windows.

It is perfect except one issue. While renaming files in finder, pressing delete will not delete the characters but will delete the whole file. Similarly, pressing backspace, will not remove the last character but will move one directory up. These are ideal behaviour in Finder but not while renaming a file in Finder.

Comment: Welcome to **Ask Different** -- RE: "Anyone know how to fix this?" --  Questions do not belong in the answer section. If you have another question then post another question.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one syntax error in your DefaultKeyBinding.dict code. The commands should also be enclosed between inverted commas. It should be:

```
 {
   "@\UF702" = "moveWordLeft:";
   "@\UF703" = "moveWordRight:";
   "@$\UF702" = "moveWordLeftAndModifySelection:";
   "@$\UF703" = "moveWordRightAndModifySelection:";
 }
```

I must say, however, that I don't find your commands in Apple's [Cocoa Events Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html). What I do see there are commands such as `moveWordForward` `moveWordBackward`. I don't find `moveWordLeftAndModifySelection`, and I don't know what you want to achieve with it, but maybe the Cocoa Events Handling Guide (the link of which I provide above) can help you.